# reactjs: trying to add and update data through a node backend and mongodb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

What I'm trying to do here is to submit a form which is completely filled in 4 steps. First step takes the title of the document. Subsequent steps just update the document.

To be more specific, on the backend, I've made 4 endpoints. In the first endpoint, I'm receiving the title from frontend form and saving it into Mongodb, which then gets assigned an id. The second endpoint (on the backend), finds the id through `findById` and updates the document with new info. The subsequent two APIs do the same.

Now, on the backend, I'm able to complete all 4 steps because I'm entering the id in POSTMAN in the route parameter and reading it through `req.params`, something like

```js
router.post('/course/step-one/:courseid', function(req, res) {
  Course.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.courseid, req.body, function(err, course) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      console.log('updated');
      res.send(course);
    }
  });
});
```

But on react frontend, I'm trying to figure out how can I pass `courseid` to the route for backend to read it as I have routes in this way in my Router.js

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path = '/step-one' component={AddCourseStep}/>
  <Route exact path = '/step-two' component={AddCourseSteptwo}/>
  <Route exact path = '/step-three' component={AddCourseStepthree}/>
  <Route exact path = '/step-four' component={AddCourseStepfour}/>
</Switch>
```

and a sample component in this way after step-one

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './add_course.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import axios from 'axios';

class add_course extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      title: '',
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const state = this.state;
    state[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(state);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { title } = this.state;
    axios
      .post('/vendor/course/step-one', {
        title,
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.props.history.push('/step-two');
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    $('.save-form a').css('color', '#fff');
  }

  render() {
    const { title } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="add-course-wrapper">
        <section>
          <div className="header-wrapper">
            <div className="header-container">
              <nav>
                <div className="container">
                  <div className="navbar-header padding-15">
                    <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle" datatoggle="collapse" datatarget="#myNavbar">
                      <span className="icon-bar"> </span>{' '}
                      <span className="icon-bar"> </span>{' '}
                      <span className="icon-bar"> </span>
                    </button>{' '}
                    <a href="/">{' '}<img src="/images/logo-small.png" />{' '}</a>{' '}
                  </div>{' '}
                  <div className="collapse navbar-collapse header-link" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li>
                        <a className="anchor-tag" href="#">
                          {' '}
                          Sign out{' '}
                        </a>{' '}
                      </li>{' '}
                      <li>
                        <a className="anchor-tag" href="#">
                          {' '}
                          Contact us{' '}
                        </a>{' '}
                      </li>{' '}
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>{' '}
        <section>
          <div className="add_course_body">
            <div className="body-container">
              <div className="add_course_form">
                <h2> Create a new course </h2>{' '}
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <div>
                    <p> All you need to do is enter a working title: </p>{' '}
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      name="title"
                      value={title}
                      className="add_course_text_field"
                      placeholder="eg Learn Java Bean Entity"
                    />
                  </div>{' '}
                  <div className="button_set pull-right no-padding">
                    <button
                      value="Save And Go"
                      type="submit"
                      className="save-form"
                    >
                      {' '}
                      Save And Go{' '}
                    </button>{' '}
                    <button className="back-previous"> Back </button>{' '}
                  </div>{' '}
                </form>{' '}
              </div>{' '}
            </div>{' '}
          </div>{' '}
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default add_course;
```

Comment: This code is unreadable. Please format it before copy to your question

Comment: You can pass json from response to your component as prop using mapStateToProps. Refer [here](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/the-react-plus-redux-container-pattern/)

Comment: @FisNaN basically you can just pay attention to handleSubmit function. All it is doing is take input from JSX form below and passing it in the backend api, and then redirecting the user to a new page.